# Full CentOS 7 image for Raspberry Pi 2 B?

Tags: raspbian

I have been searching for the 'everything' version of Centos for Raspberry as opposed to the minimal version.  I cannot find a .img download anywhere for the full CentOS version.

Also, though I got the minimal version to run, I was never able to get a GUI to run. I installed and tried GNOME and KDE, without success.  This Pi is for my 14 year old kid and I want him to be able to switch between run levels. Thoughts?

**Update** with details from comment:
I downloaded .img and sent it to SD card (bootable). That part worked well. The server booted fine. I did do the yum of GNOME and that had a couple errors about libgc and one other dependancy not found. I did update, and additional installs to get those libraries, but still nothing. I also insalled KDE, but could not get it to load either. I did my settings change systemctl graphical.default etc, but still no go! when I check the run level it says 5, but as stated never boots to graphic. 'startx' also does nothing.

Comment: What actions did you take to try to get the "GUI to run" and what was the result of those actions? Also, if you're using CentOS 7 or above, are you aware that "run levels" no longer exist and one uses systemd targets instead? If you're trying to determine whether you get a text-mode or graphical login screen at startup (though you make no mention of this in your question), that would be what you'd want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any specifics as to how you installed, but I've had issues installing the GUI piecemeal, have you tried:

yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"

Comment: Sorry for lack of details.  I downloaded .img and sent it to SD card (bootable). That part worked well.  The server booted fine. I did do the yum of GNOME and that had a couple errors about libgc and one other dependancy not found.  I did update, and additional installs to get those libraries, but still nothing.  I also insalled KDE, but could not get it to load either.  I did my settings change systemctl graphical.default etc, but still no go!  when I check the run level it says 5, but as stated never boots to graphic.  'startx' also does nothing.

Comment: @Dr.RandallLucas did you manage to get this works? I'm a dead end..

Comment: @Dr.RandallLucas Centos is really designed for use in server environments, so I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't give you a GUI at all. Have you played with Ubuntu/Raspbian?